# Regex pattern not maching in Android but matching in other platforms

Tags: android, regex

I've looked for a solution everywhere, I've tried with different regex flags, with no success.

I have the following regex pattern:

```
private static String LAST_LOG = "/.*?Last login:.*?td.*?td.*?([A-Za-z]+).*?;([0-9]+).*?;([0-9]+).*?;([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+).*?([A-Z]+)/";
```

I'm trying to find a match in this [string](http://regexr.com/3d60p).

As you can see, it's finding a match, and capturing data in 7 groups (month, day, year, hour, minute, second, timezone).

The problem is that I'm not getting a match at all, I've tested the string and it does contain the part I'm looking for, so I can't find any other reason for this to not work in Android.

```
    m = getMatcher(content,LAST_LOG);
    if(m.find()) {
        Log.e("Month",m.group(1));
        Log.e("Day",m.group(2));
        Log.e("Year",m.group(3));
        Log.e("Hour",m.group(4));
        Log.e("Minute",m.group(5));
        Log.e("Second",m.group(6));
        Log.e("Timezone",m.group(7));
    }
private static Matcher getMatcher(String str, String regex){
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    return pattern.matcher(str);
}
```

And this is not the only regexp that is causing me trouble, I have others that are currently working, but simple modifications makes them fail, even thought on other platforms (and online regex testers) they work fine.

I have the same regexp in a Python script and it's working without any problems:

```
regex_last = r'.*?Last login:.*?td.*?td.*?([A-Za-z]+).*?;([0-9]+).*?;([0-9]+).*?;([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+).*?([A-Z]+)'
m = re.search(regex_last,content.decode())
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
    print(m.group(2))
    print(m.group(3))
    print(m.group(4))
    print(m.group(5))
    print(m.group(6))
    print(m.group(7))
else:
    print('No match')
```

Outputs:

```
Apr
07
2016
17
33
52
CEST
```

I'm this close to switching to an HTML parser, but since I already had working regexps in both Python and Android and I figured using regular expressions would make it easier to switch between platforms, I decided to use them.

Comment: Remove the regex delimiters, `/` at the start and end of pattern. ICU regex does not need them, they are treated as literals. Try `private static String LAST_LOG = ".*?Last login:.*?td.*?td.*?([A-Za-z]+).*?;([0-9]+).*?;([0-9]+).*?;([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+).*?([A-Z]+)";`

Comment: As the regex string would be a constant, as would an xpath query, and everything else would change across languages, your last statement makes no sense

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks, that's what I did, I accepted Laurel's answer suggesting the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `/` from the start and end. I would also remove the `.*?` from the start as it serves no purpose but slows things down.

`private static String LAST_LOG = "Last login:.*?td.*?td.*?([A-Za-z]+).*?;([0-9]+).*?;([0-9]+).*?;([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+).*?([A-Z]+)";`

Comment: I always try hard to not post questions that had such a simple solution, I really do! So basically, I was really lucky the rest of my regex were working with the opening and closing `/` made the rest of the regular expressions match. Removed them from all patterns and removed the `.*?` as it really was innecesary. Still learning regex, thanks!